# Unable to access variable from a different class in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, class

I have 2 classes in Cocoa, but am unable to access variables from one to the other.

Class1.h:

```
@interface MyClass : NSOpenGLView
{
int myVar;
}
@property (assign) int myVar;
```

Class1.m

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthetize myVar;
...
myVar=5;
```

Class2.m

```
MyClass *theClass=[MyClass alloc];
nb=theClass.myVar;
```

==> nb=0 (instead of 5), and I am sure that the myVar=5 was executed.

What did I wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Class2`, you are creating a new instance of `MyClass`, rather than referring to an existing instance where you have previously set the `myVar` property to 5.

It's also worth mentioning that, if you needed to create a new instance of `MyClass` (that you don't), this line:

```
MyClass *theClass=[MyClass alloc];
```

should be:

```
MyClass *theClass=[[MyClass alloc] init];
```

From [Allocating and Initializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW1):

> It takes two steps to create an object using Objective-C. You must:
>
> - Dynamically allocate memory for the new object
> - Initialize the newly allocated memory to appropriate values
>
> An object isn’t fully functional until both steps have been completed.
>   Each step is accomplished by a separate method but typically in a
>   single line of code:
>
> `id anObject = [[Rectangle alloc] init];`

Comment: In `MyClass2` you are creating a new instance of `MyClass` which is different from the first instance of `MyClass`, the one that created an instance of `MyClass2`.

Comment: Thanks. So how should I refer to the existing instance ? The Class2 function (mis-)reading the value is actually started from Class1.

Comment: When you create the instance of `MyClass2`, pass either the value or a  pointer to that instance of `MyClass` so you can access the value from `MyClass2`

Comment: That starts to make sense ! So now I am in my class1, how can I retrieve its own pointer ? If I try to pass &myClass1, it doesn't accept it. Thanks !